# Por que dividir essa operação em duas causa mudança no resultado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lógica

Fiz um algoritmo simples que resolvia Fibonacci em 2 operações lógicas dentro do laço. Resolvi procurar uma maneira melhor e [encontrei uma versão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence) que faz em apenas 1 cálculo dentro do loop. Funcionou perfeitamente, mas quando fui entender a lógica apareceu um problema.

O código que gera a sequência correta é o seguinte:

```
N = int(input())
x, b, a = 0, 1, 0

while x < N:
    print('{}'.format(a), end=' ')
    a, b = b, a + b
    x += 1
```

Assim tentei decompor a lógica  `a, b = b, a + b` e os resultados começaram a dar problemas.

Por exemplo: Tanto

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

como

```
b = a + b
a = b
```

apresentam como saída uma sequência totalmente fora do esperado.

Pergunto: Qual o erro em alterar a lógica nestes casos já que eu mantive as mesmas operações lógicas embora em linhas diferentes? Tem alguma diferença por estar na mesma linha ou em linhas separadas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tem diferença. Quando na mesma linha, ambos os valores serão atualizados concomitantemente, enquanto em linhas diferentes não. Como `a` começa em zero e `b` em um, quando você faz `a, b = b, a+b`, `a` receberá o valor de `b`, 1, e `b` receberá o valor de `a+b`, 0+1=1. Perceba que o valor de `a` ainda é 0 nesta linha, pois será 1 apenas depois que a linha inteira for executada. Em linhas distintas, `b` receberia 1+1=2, quebrando a sequência.

Na mesma linha:

```
a = 0
b = 1

print('Antes:')
print('a', a)  # a 0
print('b', b)  # b 1

a, b = b, a+b

print('Depois:')
print('a', a)  # a 1
print('b', b)  # b 1
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/MiserlyHumongousAttributes) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/MJ8UTZ)</sup>

Em linhas distintas:

```
a = 0
b = 1

print('Antes:')
print('a', a)  # a 0
print('b', b)  # b 1

a = b 
b = a+b

print('Depois:')
print('a', a)  # a 1
print('b', b)  # b 2
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/HandmadeUntidyClasslibrary) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/6KJQkv)</sup>

O que acontece de fato é a construção e a desconstrução de tuplas. Analisando somente a linha `a, b = b, a + b`, o interpretador irá primeiro construir internamente uma tupla com os valores atuais de `b` e `a + b`; seria o equivalente a fazer `temp = (b, a+b)`. Depois ele fará a desconstrução desta tupla atribuindo os valores para `(a, b)`; equivalente à `(a, b) = temp`. Ou seja, primeiro é construída a tupla com os valores atuais, depois é feita a atribuição, por isso funciona como o esperado.

Utilizando a função [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis) podemos ver o que realmente acontece nessa instrução:

```
>>> print(dis.dis('a, b = b, a+b'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
              4 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              6 BINARY_ADD
              8 ROT_TWO
             10 STORE_NAME               1 (a)
             12 STORE_NAME               0 (b)
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Basicamente:

1. `LOAD_NAME`: Carrega na pilha o valor a partir do nome `b` (Pilha: `b`);
2. `LOAD_NAME`: Carrega na pilha o valor a partir do nome `a` (Pilha: `b, a`);
3. `LOAD_NAME`: Carrega na pilha o valor a partir do nome `b` (Pilha: `b, a, b`);
4. `BINARY_ADD`: Executa a soma dos dois últimos valores na pilha e carrega o resultado na pilha (Pilha: `b, a+b`);
5. `ROT_TWO`: Inverte as posições dos últimos dois valores na pilha (Pilha: `a+b, b`);
6. `STORE_NAME`: Remove um valor (`b`) da pilha e armazena no nome `a` (Pilha: `a+b`);
7. `STORE_NAME`: Remove um valor (`a+b`) da pilha e armazena no nome `b` (Pilha: vazia);

O que mostra como é armazenados antes os valores de `b` e `a+b` e somente depois é feita a atribuição.

Answer (score 2):

O que acontece é que, na expressão `a, b = b, a + b`, o valor de `a + b` é calculado antes do valor de `a` ser alterado (para `b`).

Exemplo:

```
a = 3
b = 5
a, b = b, a + b
a
=> 5
b
=> 8
```

Quando você faz um de cada vez, os valores que serão usados em `a + b` mudam antes da hora.

Exemplo:

```
a = 3
b = 5
a = b
a
=> 5
b = a + b
b
=> 10
```