# Atribuição múltipla no Python utiliza tuplas?

Tags: python, característica-linguagem, cpython

Na pergunta [Invertendo duas variáveis sem utilizar uma temporária](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/395362/5878) uma resposta cita um link que comenta sobre a atribuição múltiplas de variáveis no Python:

> **Funcionamento da Atribuição Múltipla**
>
> A atribuição múltipla é a atribuição de uma tupla a outra, onde os valores da tupla a direita do sinal de atribuição, serão atribuídos, para as respectivas variáveis, na dupla do lado esquerdo do sinal de atribuição. [sic]

Em outras referências já vi comentando parecido, que a atribuição múltipla utiliza a desconstrução de tuplas. Eu mesmo parti desta premissa para responder [Por que dividir essa operação em duas causa mudança no resultado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/277450/5878)

A fim de validar essa informação fui analisar as operações no *bytecode*:

```
from dis import dis

code = '''
a = 1
b = 3

a, b = b, a
'''

print(dis(code))
```

Que teve como saída:

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)

  3           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)

  5           8 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             12 ROT_TWO
             14 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Ou seja, ele carrega na pilha o valor de `b`, carrega na pilha o valor de `a`, permuta os dois valores dentro da pilha e faz duas atribuições, primeiro em `a`, depois em `b`. Não existe construção e desconstrução de tuplas no processo, tal como ocorre se eu realmente definir uma tupla com os dois valores:

```
from dis import dis

code = '''
a = 1
b = 3

c = b, a
'''

print(dis(code))
```

Que gera a seguinte sequência de operações:

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)

  3           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)

  5           8 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             14 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

Onde podemos ver claramente a operação `BUILD_TUPLE` sendo executada antes da atribuição.

Afinal, a atribuição múltipla usa ou não tuplas no processo? Se não, seria um *tuple-**like** assigment*, apenas para exemplificar qual valor é atribuído a cada variável?

Comment: Excelente pergunta, acompanhando....

Comment: Neste [Link](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/), principalmente neste trecho "Multiple assignment is often called “tuple unpacking” because it’s frequently used with tuples. But we can use multiple assignment with any iterable, not just tuples. Here we’re using it with a list:"  A palavra 'frequently' , a meu ver, deixa o conceito aberto e não especificando que atribuição múltipla usa tuplas.

Comment: @LuizAugusto Seria outro exemplo que talvez possa estar errado. A *tuple unpacking* que ele cita seria atribuir uma tupla que já existe na pilha para variáveis. Seria como ter `c = (1, 3)` e depois fazer `a, b = c`; aqui sim [ocorre a desconstrução de tupla](https://repl.it/@acwoss/PreviousMarvelousEmulation) (*tuple unpacking*), evidente pela operação `UNPACK_SEQUENCE`. Na atribuição múltipla não ocorre.

Comment: Veja que ele também cita "*What’s happening at a lower level is that we’re creating a tuple of...*", contrariando as operações de bytecode que coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: Correto, e contrariando ele mesmo. Fiz o debug do código, que ele cita no link, `x,y=10,20 ` . , não tenho muita experiência com debug, mas não encontrei nenhum `build_tuple` ou `build_list` Há alguma construção de tupla ou lista neste código?

Comment: @LuizAugusto Nesse caso acontece a `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` pois o valor `10, 20` é uma sequência constante. Ao invés de empilhar duas constantes, o Python já empilha a sequência com os dois valores e, para a atribuição, faz a desconstrução dela.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim - na especificação da linguagem, e para entender a sintaxe, se entende que "uma tupla é construída, seus elementos consumidos como um iterador na atribuição, e a tupla, ficando sem referências, é desalocada".

O que você vê no disassemble indica que esse pattern foi otimizado, de forma que uma atribuição apenas de troca é feita diretamente, sem a tupla intermediária.
Isso é uma otimização da implementação cPython.

Repeti seu teste aqui para a situação com 3 variáveis - também não existe a construção de uma tupla - com 4 variáveis, o disassemble já é:

```
In [6]: dis.dis(a)                                                                                                                                     
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (a)

  2           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)

  3           8 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             10 STORE_NAME               2 (c)

  4          12 LOAD_CONST               3 (4)
             14 STORE_NAME               3 (d)

  5          16 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             18 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             20 LOAD_NAME                2 (c)
             22 LOAD_NAME                3 (d)
             24 BUILD_TUPLE              4
             26 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          4
             28 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             30 STORE_NAME               3 (d)
             32 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
             34 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             36 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

E aí pode se ver o `BUILD_TUPLE`  seguido do `UNPACK_SEQUENCE`. Ou seja, a otimização só evita a construção de uma tupla, seguida de sua "desconstrução imediata" com o "UNPACK_SEQUENCE" nesses casos.

Mas bem legal você ter investigado isso - eu assumia que a tupla era construída em todos os casos, e usava a sintaxe `b, a = a, b` com um certo peso no coração por conta do desperdício, ainda que pequeno, de recursos. Vimos agora que o desperdício não acontece no cPython. (verifiquei agora no Pypy3, a otimização também existe lá)

---

Isso é o que acontece para tuplas, construídas como literais, na própria atribuição.

É importante lembrar que o "sequence unpacking" funciona de várias outras formas também para qualquer sequência ou iterável do lado direito, e é bem mais genérico do que o caso de "troca de duas variáveis".

Em particular, valem coisas do tipo:

```
In [4]: a, *b, c = range(10)                                                                                                                           

In [5]: b                                                                                                                                              
Out[5]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Nesse caso, a linguagem contou "1 elemento antes do elemento com asterisco, e 1 elemento no final" e todos os restantes (8 no caso), são atribuídos, como uma lista, à variável com "*".  (E nesse caso, não é criada uma tupla - são usados opcodes distintos para indicar como é que o elemento iterável que retornou na chamada de função vão ser distribuídos no momento da atribuição)

Outra coisa legal é que em versões mais recentes do Python, o "*" pode ser usado para descompactar uma sequência quando se está definindo outra - então dá pra fazer:

```
In [6]: a, b, c, d = 10, *range(2), 20                                                                                                                 

In [7]: a, b, c, d                                                                                                                                     
Out[7]: (10, 0, 1, 20)
```

Em to

Comment: Bem pensado os testes com mais variáveis, não havia cogitado isso.