# Erro de arumentos posicionais no Python3

Tags: python-3.x

estou fazendo um código teste para o python, e estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "teste.py", line 7, in
>   
>       g= teste('Digite um numero:  ') TypeError: teste() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'

Minha ídeia de resolver este problema é apenas para fins de estudo mesmo.
Basicamente o que eu quero que o script faça é mostrar as perguntas das variáveis g, h, i e salvar os resultados em a, b, c respectivamente.
Depois quero que minha função retorne os valores armazenados.
Se puderem me ajudar sem alterar a estrutura do código, apenas para que 
eu deixe ele funcionar de forma adequada.

```py
def teste(x, y, z):
    a= str(input(x))
    b= str(input(y))
    c= str(input(z))
    return a, b, c

#Programa principal
g= teste('Digite um numero:  ')
h= teste('Digite uma frase:  ')
i= teste('Digite um texto:  ')

teste(x=g, y=h, z=i)
print(f'{a} {b} {c}')
```

Comment: Sem alterar a estrutura não tem como, ela está errada e não faz sentido. Você fez a chamada da função 4x, sendo que nas três primeiras passou apenas um parâmetro enquanto são esperado 3, por isso o erro. Você conseguiria explicar linha a linha, como um [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) o que o seu código está fazendo?

Comment: Anderson, não conheço o teste de mesa, mas achei interessante, vou estudá-lo e montar meu código em cima dele para ver onde estou errando. A propósito, entendi o que você quis dizer com chamar 4x a função, valeu!! Quando eu disse que não queria mudar a estrutura do programa, me referi a não adicionar linhas ou sintaxes que não conheço, claro que quero deixá-lo funcional e será necessário mudar algo nesse quesito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente o que você quer é definir uma função que lê do usuário três valores e as retorne nas variáveis `a`, `b` e `c`. Se você lerá os valores do usuário não faz sentido você passar parâmetros para a função.

```py
def le_valores():
  a = input('Valor 1: ')
  b = input('Valor 2: ')
  c = input('Valor 3: ')

  return a, b, c
```

O retorno da função será uma tupla com os três valores lidos. A partir dele você poderá utilizar a [atribuição múltipla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/395398/5878) para definir os valores fora da função:

```py
g, h, i = le_valores()

print(f'{g}, {h}, {i}')
```

Exibindo, assim, os valores lidos pela função.

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson,  isto mesmo que eu queria fazer, valeu pela dica!